# Oracle ADF Glassfish MySQL - Data Source Error

Tags: mysql, glassfish-3, oracle-adf

I have set up ADF essentials library on my glassfish server as specified [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to) . I am able to successfully deploy applications to the glassfish server from jDeveloper and the application runs fine until there is a database operation involved and it is when it throws up the following error 
    **No object bound to name java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource** 
The application works fine on IntegratedWeblogicServer, so am guessing I have not set up the mysql datasource in my glassfish properly. I have setup connection as shown [here](http://mariosgaee.blogspot.in/2010/07/configure-mysql-connection-pool-in.html) and the connection name is "myDataSource" (which is same as provided in the jDeveloper's DB connection name).
Help!!!

Comment: What JNDI name did you use in Glassfish?

Comment: **jdbc/myDataSource** is the JNDI name

Comment: I tried modifying web.xml and creating sun-web.xml in my adf project(under WEB-INF folder) as specified in [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2498374) but that code wouldn't deploy, gets this error (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.hook.DeployerListenersHandler$HookDeployerListener)
Plz help, I have come too far to give up ! :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name of the datasource in your Application Module configuration tab to match the name of the datasource you defined in your GlassFish instance.